# socat - how to listen on non-ssl TCP and forward to ssl TCP endpoint?

Tags: ssl, tcp, socat

I have seen an example of using socat to accept ssl TCP traffic and forward the traffic to a non-ssl host:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:443,reuseaddr,fork "^OPENSSL-SERVER,cert=server.pem | TCP:somehost:80"
```

Is it possible to do the opposite? I.e. I have a remote host that is ssl enabled and requires a client certificate, but my client is only able to connect via non-ssl connections.

I understand the security implications of this approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer for me was:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:51000,fork,reuseaddr OPENSSL:remotehost:51000,cafile=certificate.pem,verify=0
```

The certificate didn't match the hostname so I had to switch off verification (verify=0)

Comment: For me, the `cafile` wasn't necessary.  I'm guessing it's only needed when verifying.